# Query to find node which has only one vertex in common

Tags: graph, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

I have the following vertices -

```
  Person1 -> Device1 <- Person2 
                  ^
     |            |
     v            
    Email1  <-  Person3
```

Now I want to write a gremlin query (janusgraph) which will give me all persons connected to the device(only) with which person1 is connected.
So according to the above graph, our output should be - [Person2].
Person3 is not in output because Person3 is also connected with "Email1" of "Person1".

[image]

Comment: As this was answered on the Gremlin Users e-mail list it might be nice to copy that answer here for others that come across this question. https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/yJbMw4F06QY

Comment: Sure @KelvinLawrence

Answer (score 1):

```
g.addV('person').property('name', 'Person1').as('p1'). 
  addV('person').property('name', 'Person2').as('p2').
  addV('person').property('name', 'Person3').as('p3').
  addV('device').as('d1').
  addV('email').as('e1').
  addE('HAS_DEVICE').from('p1').to('d1').
  addE('HAS_EMAIL').from('p1').to('e1').
  addE('HAS_DEVICE').from('p2').to('d1').
  addE('HAS_DEVICE').from('p3').to('d1').
  addE('HAS_EMAIL').from('p3').to('e1')
```

The following traversal will give you the person vertices that are connected to "Person1" via one or more "device" vertices and not connected via any other type of vertices.enter code here

```
g.V().has('person', 'name', 'Person1').as('p1').
  out().as('connector').
  in().where(neq('p1')).
  group().
    by().
    by(select('connector').label().fold()).
  unfold().
  where(
    select(values).
    unfold().dedup().fold().  // just in case the persons are connected by multiple devices
    is(eq(['device']))
  ).
  select(keys)
```